# Return all values from range() function and add them into an array

Tags: python, arrays, range

I'm trying to make a program which extracts specific PDF pages from a PDF file. To do this, I have an array where I put all page numbers I want to extract. However, to spare myself some time, I want to be able to add all pages between two page numbers (between 1 and 8 for instance).

Currently I have the following code:

```
def r(n1, n2):
    return range(n1, n2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pages_to_keep = [1, 2, 10, r(12,14)]
    print pages_to_keep
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 10, [12, 13]]
```

but what I want is:

```
[1, 2, 10, 12, 13, 14]
```

The thought here is that the `r` function can be called in the array to easily add multiple pages, but I want to get rid of the brackets which gets returned from the function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: try : `pages_to_keep = [1, 2, 10]+list(r(12,14))`

Comment: Is this python 2?

Comment: `pages_to_keep = [1, 2, 10, *r(12,14)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods of doing so:

1. `pages_to_keep = [1, 2, 10]+list(r(12,14))`
2. 

```
pages_to_keep = [1, 2, 10]
pages_to_keep.extend(list(r(12,14)))
```

Comment: Your method #2 doesn't actually work, since `list.extend()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jasonharper I realised that so I fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the unpacking operator (*)

```
pages_to_keep = [1,2,10, *list(r(12,14))]
```

Comment: Making it a list before unpacking is unnecessary. `[1, 2, 10, *r(12, 14)]` is valid.

Comment: Yes, that's true. To be honest not even declaring a new function for a simple range makes that much sense. Just [1, 2, 10, *range(12, 14)] should be fine.

Comment: My reasoning is that typing r instead of range is just more convenient, since I will be reusing the function many times. It also makes it look more clean, as the array contains less code. But I do agree with your point, it does make more sense to do it your suggested way, especially in terms of code readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely NOT advisable to do this   `r` = `range` in any of your projects. Changing the name of built-in functions make the code became less legible to another developers because this will be not default in any other project.

> In other words it is not pythonic and you should not do that, never!

To follow your code and to rename a function in python, just store a pointer to the function you wish, thats not necessary redefine a function for that:

```
r = range
r(1,2) # [1,2]
```

And here your answer as plain code

```
pages = [1,2]
pages.extend(r(5,8))

print(pages)
# [1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```